# How do I serialize Moose objects to XML?

Tags: xml, perl, serialization, moose

I have a bunch of legacy modules I want to convert to being Moose-based. The modules currently have "toXML" methods, which are hand-coded using XML::LibXML.

Is there a module or technique for serializing Moose objects to XML?

I have looked at MooseX::Storage, but that handles JSON, YAML, and Storage, not XML. A google search for Moose and XML yields lots of references to XML::Rabbit, which seems to be good for parsing XML into Moose classes, but there's not a lot out there for taking Moose objects and serializing them to XML.

The 6-year-old thread at http://grokbase.com/t/perl/moose/11akp809sr/java-annotation-net-attributes-in-moose is extremely close to what I want to do, but there doesn't seem to be any followup on it.

Comment: The [MooseX::Storage](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/MooseX-Storage-0.52/lib/MooseX/Storage.pm) does it by using [MooseX::Storage::Format::JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/MooseX-Storage-0.52/lib/MooseX/Storage/Format/JSON.pm) role.  From what I can see, it's the only `MooseX::Storage::Format` serialization role our there.  Perhaps write your own? Code for `Format::JSON` is a few dozen lines (using a module). I don't know what exactly you need to serialize, but maybe [XML::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~mikewong/XML-Dumper-0.81/Dumper.pm) can help. It claims to be able to work with objects.

Comment: @zdim, Re "*From what I can see, it's the only MooseX::Storage::Format serialization role our there*", MooseX::Storage::Format::JSON, ...::YAML, and ...::Storable all come with MooseX::Storage.

Comment: @Blaise Pascal, So write MooseX::Storage::Format::XML.

Comment: @ikegami  Right. I meant to say that I didn't see any other modules under `MooseX::Storage::Format`

Comment: Something you have to take into account when working with MooseX::Storage is what when you for example keep objects in a key/value store (e.g. product objects in an ecom application), and you have lots of different sub-classes for different product types, you have to load all of these sub-classes somewhere in the application, because MooseX::Storage cannot do that for you. You could teach it to do that of course, but it's easier to just load all those classes, e.g. in your main application class.

Comment: @ikegami If only I were being paid to write it.

Answer (score 4):

The [MooseX::Storage](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eether/MooseX-Storage-0.52/lib/MooseX/Storage.pm) serializes data in `JSON` by using [MooseX::Storage::Format::JSON](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eether/MooseX-Storage-0.52/lib/MooseX/Storage/Format/JSON.pm) *role*, which is a good example for how to plug in other formats.   I cannot see any roles for `XML` serialization, but it is easy to write your own and the module provides a hook for it.

This minimal example shows how to write a *role* and *consume* (use) it in a class. A role is a class-like package which never gets instantiated on its own but is rather absorbed by other classes. It is meant to provide functionality that can be easily "plugged" in, and used by multiple classes. At the end it is shown how to hook the new role into `MooseX::Storage` and so use it in your class.

It uses [XML::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emikewong/XML-Dumper-0.81/Dumper.pm) for serialization itself, mostly as a placeholder for custom code (if needed).

**Point.pm**

```
package Point;    

use Moose;

use overload  q("") => sub { 
    my $self = shift; 
    return '(' . $self->x . ', ' . $self->y . ')' 
};  

has 'x' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Int', required => 1, default => 0); 
has 'y' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Int', required => 1, default => 0); 

with 'SerializeXML';

sub BUILD { print "Created a Point $_[0]\n" }

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;    
1;
```

The only specific statement here is the line `with 'SerializeXML';`

**SerializeXML.pm**

```
package SerializeXML;

use Moose::Role;    
use XML::Dumper;

sub to_xml {
    my ($self) = shift;
    return XML::Dumper->new->pl2xml($self);  # or use custom code
}

sub from_xml {
    my ($self, $xml) = @_; 
    return XML::Dumper->new->xml2pl($xml);
}
    
no Moose::Role;
1;
```

The construction of an object from `XML` should be done via `new`, and/or as a class method.

**main**

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Point;

my $pt = Point->new(x => 10, y => 12);

my $obj_xml = $pt->to_xml;
print "$obj_xml\n";

my $obj = $pt->from_xml($obj_xml);
print "Object via role: $obj\n";
```

This prints

```
Created a Point (10, 12)
<perldata>
 <hashref blessed_package="Point" memory_address="0x1691438">
  <item key="x">10</item>
  <item key="y">12</item>
 </hashref>
</perldata>
Object via role: (10, 12)
```

Methods for writing to and loading from a file can be added. But now you have a ready role which can be hooked to `MooseX::Storage`, as shown below.

I don't know nor have tested how well `XML::Dumper` works with `Moose`. Please test and if it doesn't cut it for your needs swap calls to it with your own code that does what you need.

---

The remaining step is to integrate this in `MooseX::Storage`, if desired.

There are two necessary small changes to make in the above code. Use role in `Point` as

```
use MooseX::Storage;

with Storage(format => '=SerializeXML', io => 'File');
```

and rename `to_xml` and `from_xml` to `freeze` and `thaw` (or add these, with same code).

Then you can use `store` and `load` in `main` in order to write to `$file` and load from it

```
$pt->store($file);
my $pt_new = Point->load($file);
```

The syntax `=PackageName` is for a namespace prefix other than `MooseX::Storage::Format::`

For roles see [Moose::Manual::Roles](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eether/Moose-2.2004/lib/Moose/Manual/Roles.pod) and [Moose::Cookbook::Roles::](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=+Moose%3A%3ACookbook%3A%3ARoles%3A%3A&mode=all) namespace (examples).

Comment: This is a really nice guide. If XML is desired specifically we can assume that the OP knows their way around XML, so instead of XML::Dumper, maybe XML::Compile could be an alternative. If they write an actual XML schema and feed it into XML::Compile along with the data, they can even easily accept data from external sources to create objects from directly just by giving out the schema.

Comment: @simbabque  Thank you. It was meant to be basic. I didn't want to touch the `XML` processing, as that is another problem. That is a nice idea that you offer. Perhaps the OP should ask about `XML` as a separate question, with a description of what they are doing and why they chose that format.

Comment: I'm dealing with legacy code/legacy data, so I didn't choose the XML format, merely inherited it from someone who made that decision a decade or two ago. Unfortunately, this means that `XML::Dumper` can't be used, as it doesn't dump the right format.

The existing `MooseX::Storage::Format` modules basically encapsulate an existing dumper like `XML::Dumper`, but don't give any control over the format. That's not what I need.

Comment: @BlaisePascal  Hang on ... in the above code you can plug in any `XML` processing that you want.  (For example, your/theirs existing libraries, if they work.) It gives you the _framework to switch to Moose_, which is what you aks about in my understanding.  That's why I didn't touch `XML` -- I used `XML::Dumper` as a place-holder for details of the specific `XML` processing.  Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @BlaisePascal  There are no "_existing `MooseX::Storage::Format` modules_" for `XML` (as far as I can tell).  But the whole `MooseX::Storage` is written so that it is easy to plug in "roles" for any desrired format, which is what I meant to show above.  Then you write/use suitable code for your particular purpose.  Again, I am following the "_want to convert to being Moose-based_" -- you add a role using existing code (if it works).

Answer (score 2):

So one of the reasons why `MooseX::Storage` doesn't have a XML storage format is that as you've discovered, most people have a legacy format for XML that they need to write to. XML and Perl actually have very different ways of representing data and figuring that out the right way to translate between the two isn't actually something you can do automatically.

You're not going to find an "off the shelf" option per-se. As  simbabque mentions in a comment if you have or can easily build a Schema for your data then `XML::Compile` or 'XML::Pastor`might work for you (`XML::Compile`is better maintained). If you're willing to do some grunt work`XML::Toolkit`is designed to translate an example document into a series of Moose classes that it can then later re-serialize. However I haven't touched`XML::Toolkit` in a *long* time so YMMV on what it needs to get running.

I think that ultimately you'll find that the simplest solution is the one you already have, hand-built `toXML` methods. Moose doesn't stop you from doing that, and in fact gives you a bunch of tools to figure out how to make it more maintainable. Look at how MooseX::Storage itself is implemented to see a good path forward.