# roles and code readability

Tags: perl, moose, moo

The improvement of using roles (Moo::Role or Role::Tiny or whatever)

```
with qw(
    Some::Role
    Some::Other::Role
);
...
some_roles_method();
```

over just explicitly importing the function from the mixin class

```
use Some::Role qw/some_roles_method/;
...
some_roles_method();
```

are numerous, and include added flexibility, less bookkeeping (especially if there are a lot of methods being imported), and not overwriting existing methods.

But a big drawback is if you're reading the code and come across mentions of `some_roles_method()` and you want to read the function, it's not immediately apparent where to go. All you can tell is that it's not defined in *this* file.

Are there any good strategies for handling that? Am I the only one that bothers?

Comment: That is not the only role of roles (no pun intended.) For example, [`requires`](https://www.nu42.com/2010/07/beauty-of-moose-enforcing-interface.html) can come in handy. If you don't buy in to the sugar these modules provide, SO is not the place to have a debate about it.

Comment: Given how it's called the only place to go to is the package (class).  Then you look for `with` there and see the role's package name.  It shouldn't be much of a problem?

Comment: Given your snippet, let me say this just in case -- roles are used with a class and are absorbed by it (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42465412/4653379) for example).  Then locating the method shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of, and that I do once in a while, is to document everything thoroughly with [POD](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html). But of course that requires *a lot* of discipline.

```
use Moo;
with 'Role::Reader', 'Role::Writer';

# ...

=head1 METHODS

=head2 frobnicate

Frobnicates the foo.

=cut

sub frobnicate { ... }

=head2 write_cheque

This method is documented in L<Role::Writer>.

=head2 write_autograph

This method is documented in L<Role::Writer>.

=head2 read_mind

This method is documented in L<Role::Reader>.

=head2 read_book

This method is documented in L<Role::Reader>.

=cut

1;
```

Comment: Are there tools to automate the locating of the "source" of a method?

Comment: @Ed. Can you be more specific? Are you talking about introspection on an object to tell which method code cone from what file and line?

Comment: I guess yes, or at least from which class?

Comment: @Ed. For what purpose? When you have an object you can inspect it for methods.